# Angular '<controller> as <variable>' is not a function, got undefined at Error (native)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been trying to make a very simple angular app to create a more visually appealing portoflio, but I can't seem to get through this error. I've tried many things without success and was hoping you guys could help me indentify the mistake. Thanks in advance!

The error:

```
Error: Argument 'MainController as portfolio' is not a function, got undefined at Error (native)
```

Here's the code for the html & js:

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('PortfolioApp',[]);

  app.controller('MainController', function(){
    this.projects = projects;
  });

  var projects = [<info>];

})();
```

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Luis Lamadrid - Projects</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class='container'>
          <div class='row-centered'>
            <div class='col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2'>

              <div id='content' ng-app=PortfolioApp ng-controller='MainController as portfolio'>
                <h1>{{ understand }}</h1>

                <div ng-repeat='project in portfolio.projects'>
                  <h2>
                  {{ project.name }}
                  <small> - {{ project.started_date }}</small>
                  <a href="{{project.link}}" class="no-deco right"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i></a>
                  </h2>
                  <h2>

                  </h2>
                  <br>
                  {{ project.description }}<br><br>
                  <small>Developed on: <em>{{ project.framework }}</em> </small>
                  <hr>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- row-centered -->
        </div> <!-- container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using Angular 1.0.7

Comment: Yup, you should use at least v. 1.2+ if you want the majority of people to give you proper answers.

Answer (score 1):

In your Html you should define ng-app like that. `<html ng-app="AppName">` and you should use more resent version of angular if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Yeoman if you don't know what you are doing, then at-least you get best practice code up and running to start modifying. http://yeoman.io/
2. There is no need for "MainController as portfolio" in your code, I can't see you will used mixed scopes etc. Just use "MainController". And move out the ng-app from there.
3. Your code is totally broken, for example what is var projects = []; doing there out of a controller or service, etc.
4. ng-app should always be declared in the html element tag.
5. Next time do a plunker, you can create a AngularJS plunker directly and get hacking, then it is easier to help you out.
6. I suggest you do a good tutorial in AngularJS before you get going, else you will get stuck for sure a lot of times.
7. Don't ever use jQuery with Angular, there is jQuery version of any thing you want almost, for example ui-bootstrap.